# Improper query escaping in the return URL after logging in

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, character-escaping, url-encoding

Something is causing my query search `[javascript] -[php] votes:0 is:question` to turn into `javascript -php votes:0 is:question` after signing in.

Steps to reproduce:

- Make sure you are *not* connected
- Search for any query containing tags (still not connected)
- On the results page, click *log in*
- Connect via any(?) of the possibilities (I used Gmail (I was already signed in on Gmail (just in case that matters (sorry for the nested parenthesis))))
- Check if your query was properly escaped
- <del>Open a bug report on meta</del>
- <del>Have your question closed as a dupe of [Improper query escaping in the return URL after logging in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147779/improper-query-escaping-in-the-return-url-after-loging-in)</del>

Comparing the two URLs:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+-[php]+votes%3A0+is%3Aquestion
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+-php+votes:0+is:question
```

The return URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fsearch%3fq%3djavascript%2b-php%2bvotes%3a0%2bis%3aquestion
```

Also, I didn't tag this SO since I believe it happens on all sites

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169356/23354