# Redirect to questions list tagged with the tags's names complained after login

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, login, redirection

Suppose I currently browse the following:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/"tag1" or "tag2" or "tag3"...
```

To get the list of questions for these tags. If I browse to this url and I was not logged in, then if I clicked the login button to login in, after I logged in, it redirects me to:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1tag2tag3...
```

And it gives me a list of questions tagged with the following tag `[tag1tag2tag3...]`

For example, before log in:

> [image: Before I logged In]

**After I logged in:**

> [image: After I logged in]

I know it is not a big issue for me, but I thought I should report that. So my questions are:

- Is this a bug?
- Suppose that this happened because of the use of the `or` to get what I want, What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me..

Comment: Likely related: [Improper query escaping in the return URL after logging in](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147779)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this bug has been resolved now. I tried the following steps:

1. Opened the following link in a new incognito window of Chrome (because I was logged-in in normal window)
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+or+sql+or+sql-server+or+sql-server-2008+or+sqlite
2. Then clicked on `Log in` and logged-in with my Gmail account.
3. And it redirected me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql%2bor%2bsql%2bor%2bsql-server%2bor%2bsql-server-2008%2bor%2bsqlite (here `%2b` is used instead of `+`)

#### Before Login

> [image]

#### After Login

> [image]

Comment: Yes, it is now resolved too in Mozilla Firefox, thanks